# variable expansion within a here-string, powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following variable that contains other variables:

```
$jsontemplate = @"
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "trigger.update",
    "params": {
        "triggerid": "$($zabbixtriggerid)",
        "status": 1
    },
                                               "id": "$($zabbixAuth.id)",
                                               "auth": "$($zabbixAuth.auth)"
                                               }
"@
```

$($xxx.yyy) format works fine if I run the script manually but I cannot use it because the program that runs the script uses tokens in $() format to insert strings into powershell scripts and will go crazy. Any other way to achieve the same effect? When I use just $xxx.yyy format, .yyy part gets ignored. It gets interpreted only when I use $() format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a format string to pass the values:

```
$jsontemplate = @"
{{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "trigger.update",
    "params": {{
        "triggerid": "{0}",
        "status": 1
    }},
    "id": "{1}",
    "auth": "{2}"
    }}
"@ -f $zabbixtriggerid, $zabbixAuth.id, $zabbixAuth.auth
```

Look at the last line where I format the string using the three variables.

Comment: as soon as I add -f $zabbixtriggerid, $zabbixAuth.id, $zabbixAuth.auth part, I get the following error: Error formatting a string: Input string was not in a correct format..

Comment: Oh, seems like you have to escape the curly brackets using two of them. I updat may answer